# How to detect my application is terminated by TASKKILL in Command Prompt?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, hook

My purpose want to catch TASKKILL event in Command Prompt, and use this event.

Maybe, I think need to use `kernel32.dll` but I can't find a handler for this.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool TerminateProcess(IntPtr hProcess, uint uExitCode);
```

**Update**

Follow ways @Ben Voigt suggest:

**_Using WMI:**

Step 1: Run the command `mgmtclassgen Win32_Process /n root\cimv2 /o WMI.Win32` to generate the class `Process`. And then renaming the class `Process` to `Win32_Process`.

http://notepad.cc/share/3SQfeJgEQR

Step 2: Create a class with name `ProcessWatcher`

http://notepad.cc/share/UIR1Tw5twy

Step 3: Using this class with `while` loop for waiting my application status.
This is easy way but not my choice.

http://notepad.cc/share/JXLGogGbai

**_Using Window Hook:**

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool DuplicateHandle(IntPtr hSourceProcessHandle,
           ushort hSourceHandle, IntPtr hTargetProcessHandle, out IntPtr lpTargetHandle,
           uint dwDesiredAccess, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bInheritHandle, uint dwOptions);
```

But `TerminateProcess` and `DuplicateHandle`, I can't find a handler for this.

Comment: Why would you want this? The only software I know for willing to do this are viruses....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From some other process, which we shall call the watchdog, you must get a handle to the process you will monitor for termination (the target process).  You can have a handle created using `DuplicateHandle` and communicated via an IPC mechanism.  If you know the PID of the target process, you can use `OpenProcess` or `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById`.  If the target process is spawned by the watchdog, you get a handle from `CreateProcess` or `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`.  Or you can enumerate running processes, for example using `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName`.

In any case, once you have a handle to the process, you can pass it to one of the wait functions such as `WaitForSingleObject`, `WaitForMultipleObjects`, or `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx`.  When the process ceases running, for example because TASKKILL terminated it, the process handle becomes signaled and the wait will complete.

If you use the .NET `Process` class and its `WaitForExit` method, be aware that unlike the Win32 wait functions, there is no multi-handle version; you'll need to dedicate an entire thread.

---

A possibly easier way is to use WMI and subscribe to process events.  I tend not to use WMI myself, but it could be useful if you don't have a parent/child relationship between watchdog and target, making the handle otherwise difficult to get.  You can read about it on this blog:

- [Using WMI to monitor process creation, deletion and modification in .NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/438006)

Comment: Thanks for answer. But can you send me a example using DuplicateHandle, please? I can't find a example for this :)

Comment: Because I'm learning using Window Hook. I need a detail example.

Comment: Actually DuplicateHandle is better for other kinds of handles, because you need the process handle before you can call it.  Use one of the other three methods (by id, by name, or returned during creation) to get a process handle.

Comment: +1 Using WMI is the easy way. But I still use a handler (DuplicateHandle), but it's available with C++ :(